# How to inset faces with scale in to the center of the face?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image: Image showing regular mesh]

[image: Image showing distorted mesh]

Is there any way to inset a face with a scale property to avoid the mesh from distorting?

1. The top image is a figure representing the face I am trying to inset.
2. The bottom image is a figure representing the distorted mesh after inset.

As seen from the following images the inset causes distortion in the mesh. Is there any way to avoid this, possibly by using a proportional property or scale setting to avoid unnecessary overlapping of the mesh?

Comment: Which command did you try? Inset with "I" ?

Comment: Yes I was insetting with the "I" command.

Comment: plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail inspection